# Woocommerce archive-product.php template function broken after update 3.3.0 / 3.3.1

Tags: php, wordpress, function, templates, woocommerce

I've been using the code below for a number of years with no problems what so ever until I upgraded to Woocommerce version 3.1.1.

The function simply changes the default archive-product.php to an alternative template based on the defined Woocommerce category slug.

I've read through the change logs and there are a few things I think that may be connected to my problem but I'm not sure, hence why I'm reaching out here :)

The relevant note from the changelog to me seemed to be:

> Fix – Added woocommerce_output_product_categories to replace
>      woocommerce_product_subcategories function to prevent outdated theme
>      template files from outputting categories on the shop and category
>      pages in err.

However, there were many changes made to the default layout/theme of Woocommerce in the previous version 3.3.0 which may also be at fault.

Any help or guidance on this one would be awesome.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse138858_woocommerce_category_archive_template' );

function wpse138858_woocommerce_category_archive_template( $original_template ) {

    if ( is_product_category( array( 'cat-1', 'cat-2' ) ) )
    {
        return get_stylesheet_directory().'/woocommerce/archive-product_no_sidebar.php';
    }
    elseif ( is_product_category( array( 'cat-3', 'cat-4' ) ) )
    {
        return get_stylesheet_directory().'/woocommerce/archive-product_sidebar.php';
    } 
    elseif ( is_product_category( array( 'cat-5', 'cat-6' ) ) )
    {
        return get_stylesheet_directory().'/woocommerce/archive-product_clubs_page.php';
    } 
    else 
    {
        return $original_template;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** - There were errors in the function that shouldn't have been there, my fault, sorry... I have copied the code straight from the live site and just cut the category down so its more readable

Comment: sorry this was my mistake in copying the code over, i have added the } back in which is how it is on my live site and the issue is still there

Comment: Could you tell us what is broken exactly ? What does it displaying or not displaying ?

Comment: before updating to Woocommerce 3.3.0 - 3.3.1 this function would load a different archive-product.php template file based on the category slugs supplied in the array. after the update the function stopped working and the default archive-product.php is always loaded

Comment: @Jonnygogo Woocommerce 3.3.1 is very new and still with some bugs. Also a lot of Themes and plugins have not all been updated to work with. So version 3.3.1 is not ready for production web sites… You should [roll back in 3.2.6 stable version](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/advanced/) and wait a few time as there is a lot of issues around `template_include` hook with Woocommerce 3.3+ here on StackOverFlow and all over internet related threads…

Comment: thanks for the heads up loicTheAztec, there was a db update somewhere along the way do you know which version this occurred in?

Comment: I was facing the same issue in version 3.3.0. I rolled back to version 3.2.6, template_include() is working fine now. Thank you @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @vedu Glad it was useful for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install plugin WP Rollback and then click rollback in the installed plugins menu on woocommerce. Had to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` statement is in your `elseif` statement. you have to put it after like this :

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse138858_woocommerce_category_archive_template' );
function wpse138858_woocommerce_category_archive_template( $original_template ) {

    // If cat 1,2,3 return template archive product set 1
    if(is_product_category(array('cat-1','cat-2','cat-3'))) {

        return get_stylesheet_directory().'/woocommerce/archive-product_set_1.php';

    // If cat 4,5,6 return template archive product set 2
    }elseif(is_product_category(array('cat-4','cat-5','cat-6'))) {

        return get_stylesheet_directory().'/woocommerce/archive-product_set_2.php';

    // Else return original template
    }else {

        return $original_template;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry this was my mistake in copying the code over, i have added the } back in which is how it is on my live site and the issue is still there

Comment: You still have one "}"  spare

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks, i have recopied the code from my live site and only removed some of the categories this time. as it was working before the update im assuming this is error free?